# convert value of json object from string in array to number using floatparse

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I  have a array with json objects. some objects properties  values I  need to convert to number from string. I  need to push converted number value json to new list.  I  tried using floatparse but didnt succeed.
code

```
var json = [{
    "id" : "0", 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "cost" : "250.24",
    "discount": "10"
},
{
    "id" : "1", 
    "msg"   : "there",
    "cost" : "45.00",
    "discount": "0"
}];

var  json1 = [];

for (var key in json) {
       if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    
          for (const prop in json[key]) {        
          const parsed = parseFloat(json[key][prop]);              
          res[key][prop] = isNaN(parsed) ? json[key][prop] : parsed;                                        
           //  need to  push  array of modified json object value converted to number from string into json1  
          }
         
       }
    }
```

Comment: Given your `json` input example, providing the expected `json1` output would help.

Answer (score 1):

### As objects

I prefer a map solution:

```js
var json = [{
    "id": "0",
    "msg": "hi",
    "cost": "250.24",
    "discount": "10"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "msg": "there",
    "cost": "45.00",
    "discount": "0"
  }
];

const json1 = json.map(obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
    return [
      key,
      isNaN(parsedValue) ? value : parsedValue
    ];
  })));

console.log(json1);
```

To take it back to loops however:

```js
var json = [{
    "id": "0",
    "msg": "hi",
    "cost": "250.24",
    "discount": "10"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "msg": "there",
    "cost": "45.00",
    "discount": "0"
  }
];

const json1 = [];

for (const obj of json) {
  const mappedObj = {};

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
    mappedObj[key] = isNaN(parsedValue) ? value : parsedValue;
  }

  json1.push(mappedObj);
}

console.log(json1);
```

### As arrays

```js
var json = [[
    {key:"id", value:"0"},
    {key:"msg", value:"hi"},
    {key:"cost", value:"250.24"},
    {key:"discount", value:"10"}
  ],
  [
    {key:"id", value:"1"},
    {key:"msg", value:"there"},
    {key:"cost", value:"45.00"},
    {key:"discount", value:"0"}
  ]
];

const json1 = json.map(obj =>
  obj.map(({key, value}) => {
    const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
    return {
      key,
      value: isNaN(parsedValue) ? value : parsedValue
    };
  }));

console.log(json1);
```

Comment: output is like this[{
  cost: 250.24,
  discount: 10,
  id: 0,
  msg: "hi"
}, {
  cost: 45,
  discount: 0,
  id: 1,
  msg: "there"
}] not in order

Comment: Two things, in my browser, I hit Run code snippet and I get them put out in order `[{"id": 0,"msg": "hi","cost": 250.24,"discount": 10},{"id": 1,"msg": "there","cost": 45,"discount": 0}]` Second thing you should NOT be relying on property order of js objects. It is not guaranteed, and we've just proven that with different results.

Comment: If order matters, I'd suggest a different data structure. Either represent the objects as arrays instead or use a Map. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/9360315)

Answer (score 1):

your loop are wrong.

`for (var key in json)` => when you use loop over an `array` it's return `item` index not key

`json.hasOwnProperty(key)` => your json is an `array` you don't need to use `hasOwnProperty` it's for `object`

I wrote 2 way for you:

*: you can use `+` for convert `string` to `number`.

*: if you want loop over item keys you can use `way1`, check `Object.entries`, `Object.keys`, `Object.values` methods.

```js
const json = [{
    "id" : "0", 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "cost" : "250.24",
    "discount": "10"
},
{
    "id" : "1", 
    "msg"   : "there",
    "cost" : "45.00",
    "discount": "0"
}];

//way1
const json1 = json.map((item)=>{
    return Object.entries(item).reduce((pre,[key,value])=>{
        const parsed = +value
        pre[key] = isNaN(parsed) ? value : parsed
        return pre
    },{})
})
console.log('json1',json1)

//way2
const json2 = json.map((item)=>{
    return {
        "id": +item.id,
        "msg": item.msg,
        "cost": +item.cost,
        "discount": +item.discount,
    }
})
console.log('json2',json2)
```

Comment: `for (var key in json)` will give you key (index), not the values, you're thinking `for (var key of json)`

Comment: Run `for (var key in [1,2,3]) console.log(key)` vs `for (var key of [1,2,3]) console.log(key)`

Comment: yes i forgot to write index

Comment: yes  way 1  works  but   order of objects is changed. cost becomes 1st. objects are n  numbered. dynamic. I  need in same order[{
    "id" : 0, 
    "msg"   : "hi",
    "cost" : 250.24,
    "discount": 10
},...]

Comment: yes, because loop over `item` keys. I wrote `way1` like your code. and loop over keys.

Comment: is it possible order unchanged with way1?

Comment: it's loop `keys`, if your `keys` of object order change it's change. if order of keys are important `way2` is better